# .htaccess of getsimple gets me a 500 Internal Server Error on Ubuntu Localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver

localhost setup

ubuntu 12.04

mod rewrite enabled

multiple sites running in different directory’s

dir structure

```
/var/www/mysite1/htdocs/
/var/www/filehostwatch.com/htdocs/
.
.
.
```

wordpress .htaccess that works in my getsimple dir(copyed for test reasons) without problems

the one from getsimple gives me a 500 The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration ... i later figured out that this section is what caussing the error

**.htacess**

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

**now the section that causes errors**

```
Options -Indexes

# blocks direct access to the XML files - they hold all the data!
<Files ~ "\.xml$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>
<Files sitemap.xml>
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>
```

**end of the section that causese 500 errors**

```
RewriteEngine on

# Usually it RewriteBase is just '/', but 
# replace it with your subdirectory path
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

the config file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ of the site looks like the one with another site where wordpress is running without problems. and as i said the htaccess from wordpress works even in this site when copied over.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName filehostwatch.localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/filehostwatch.com/htdocs
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/filehostwatch.com/htdocs/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride FileInfo
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea what might cause this problem?

Comment: 500 means go and check your error_log. What does it say?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably change `Satisfy All` to `Satisfy Any` in the offending section to see if it helps.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Options All -Indexes

# blocks direct access to the XML files - they hold all the data!
<Files ~ "\.xml$">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
<Files sitemap.xml>
    Satisfy Any
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine On

# Usually it RewriteBase is just '/', but 
# replace it with your subdirectory path
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly... `.htaccess` is in your `/var/www/filehostwatch.com/htdocs/` directory? In which case I don't think you're giving enough permissions for your `.htaccess` file to configure what you want... In your virtual host settings you have:

```
<Directory /var/www/filehostwatch.com/htdocs/>
    ...
    AllowOverride FileInfo
    ...
</Directory>
```

Which gives the ability to change mod_rewrite settings, but doesn't permit changing of host accesses (e.g. `Allow` & `Deny`) nor the changing of `Options`.

Have you tried setting this to `AllowOverride All` in your virtual host config? Alternatively you could add more directive settings to the AllowOverride option. Offhand I think `AllowOverride FileInfo Limit Options` should do the trick.

See also [Apache's doc on AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)